# WordPress, setup_postdata creating unexpected results(skipping every second input)

Tags: php, wordpress, post, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working with ACF on WordPress just trying to pull in what are basically custom blog posts to use as information cards. The set up allows me to choose the blog posts(maximum of 4) from a list of all of them using a custom field. This is my code

```
<?php
$post_object = get_field('resource_one');
$post = $post_object;
setup_postdata( $post );
echo '<a href="' ;
echo get_the_permalink( $post_object ) ;
echo '">' ;
echo '<div class="resource-box">' ;
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_object );
echo '<div id="resource-category-confirmation">' ;
echo the_field('resource_category');
echo '</div>' ;
echo '<p>' ;
echo get_the_title( $post_object );
echo '</p>' ;
echo '</div>' ;
echo '</a>' ;

$post_object = get_field('resource_two');
$post = get_field('resource_two');
setup_postdata( $post );
echo '<a href="' ;
echo get_the_permalink( $post_object ) ;
echo '">' ;
echo '<div class="resource-box">' ;
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_object );
echo '<div id="resource-category-confirmation">' ;
echo the_field('resource_category');
echo '</div>' ;
echo '<p>' ;
echo get_the_title( $post_object );
echo '</p>' ;
echo '</div>' ;
echo '</a>'  ?>

<?php
$post_object = get_field('resource_three');
$post = $post_object;
setup_postdata( $post );
echo '<a href="' ;
echo get_the_permalink( $post_object ) ;
echo '">' ;
echo '<div class="resource-box">' ;
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_object );
echo '<div id="resource-category-confirmation">' ;
echo the_field('resource_category');
echo '</div>' ;
echo '<p>' ;
echo get_the_title( $post_object );
echo '</p>' ;
echo '</div>' ;
echo '</a>'  
?>

<?php
$post_object = get_field('resource_four');
$post = $post_object;
setup_postdata( $post );
echo '<a href="' ;
echo get_the_permalink( $post_object ) ;
echo '">' ;
echo '<div class="resource-box">' ;
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_object );
echo '<div id="resource-category-confirmation">' ;
echo the_field('resource_category');
echo '</div>' ;
echo '<p>' ;
echo get_the_title( $post_object );
echo '</p>' ;
echo '</div>' ;
echo '</a>'  ?>
```

For some reason the first and third load completely fine the the second and fourth won't pull any of the information, I currently even have them all set to the same blog post and only the first and third will load. No matter how many I add it's always the even numbered ones that don't load their data and the odd numbered ones that do. I'm sure the solution is fairly simple and I'm just missing it. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Solved this. I need to add

```
if ( $post ) :
```

at the top and

```
wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

at the bottom of each call.